# Format date strings comprising weeks and quarters as Date objects

Tags: r, zoo, lubridate

I have dates in an R dataframe column formatted as character strings as `WK01Q32014`.

I want to turn each date into a `Date()` object.

So I altered the format to make it look like `01-3-2014`. I want to try to do something like `as.Date("01-3-2014","%W-%Q-%Y")` for example, but there is no format code for quarters that I know of.

Is there any way to do this using the `lubridate`, `zoo`, or any other libraries?

Comment: Quarter+Week won't uniquely specify a date. How does it know which day of the week to use? What do you expect "WK01Q32014" to become? R date values have to be able to resolve to month+date+year.

Comment: This is similar to the "week of the year" problem, but more frequent... you need to determine which week is considered the "first" week of the quarter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know of any specific function, but here's a basic one:

```
convert_WQ_to_Date <- function(D) {
  weeks   <- as.integer(substr(D, 3, 4))
  quarter <- as.integer(substr(D, 6, 6))
  year    <- substr(D, 7, 10)


  days <- 7 * ((quarter - 1) * 13 + (weeks-1))
  as.Date(sprintf("%s-01-01", year)) + days
}
```

Example

```
D <- c("WK01Q32014", "WK01Q12014", "WK05Q42014", "WK01Q22014", "WK02Q32014")

convert_WQ_to_Date(D)
[1] "2014-07-02" "2014-01-01" "2014-10-29" "2014-04-02" "2014-07-09"
```

Comment: So are you assuming there are W00 values for the "first" week? It's was surprising that "WK01Q12014" didn't return Jan 1 because by the 8th you should be in the second week.

Comment: @MrFlick, Whoops! No, I had forgotten the ` - 1` for weeks.  I edited my answer.  Thanks for catching that

Comment: That's better. You're still making a lot of assumptions (for example that quarters start every 13 weeks, not necessarily at the start of every third month) and that the day of the week returned for any given year will always be the same as the first day of the year. Not that these are bad assumptions, it's just possible that others may have different definitions of what date corresponds to  "the second week of the third quarter". It's not a well defined term.

Answer (score 1):

The week, quarter and year does not uniquely define a date so we will have to add some assumption.  Here we add the assumption that the first week is the first day of the quarter, the second week is 7 days later and so on,

Below, we extract the qtr-year part and use `as.yearqtr` in the zoo package to convert that to a `yearqtr` object and then use `as.Date` to convert that to a date which is the first of the quarter.  We then extract the week, subtract 1 and multiply by 7 to get the days offset.  Adding the first of the quarter to the offset gives the result:

```
library(zoo)

xx <- "01-3-2014" # week-quarter-year
qtr.start <- as.Date(as.yearqtr(sub("...", "", xx), "%q-%Y"))
days <- 7 * (as.numeric(sub("-.*", "", xx)) - 1)
qtr.start + days
## [1] "2014-07-01"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the traditional notion of each quarter starting respectively at the 1st January, 1st April, 1st July and 1st September (in line with the `quarters` function), just start at these dates and add 7 days for each week:

```
x <- c("01-3-2014","01-1-2014","05-4-2014","01-2-2014","02-3-2014")

y <- as.numeric(substr(x,6,9))
m <- as.numeric(substr(x,4,4))
d <- as.numeric(substr(x,1,2))

as.Date(paste(y,(m-1)*3+1,"01",sep="-")) + (7*(d-1))
#[1] "2014-07-01" "2014-01-01" "2014-10-29" "2014-04-01" "2014-07-08"
```